# Detect desynchronization in HOTP authentication

Tags: authentication, one-time-password, hotp

In HOTP authentication, is there a way for a system to detect that the token has been desynchronized? If so how does it know that the OTP was generated from a desynchronized (but valid) token and is not just a fake/random OTP?

Answer (score 4):

From [RFC 4226](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt):

> 7.4.  Resynchronization of the Counter
>
> Although the server's counter value is only incremented after a
>   successful HOTP authentication, the counter on the token is
>   incremented every time a new HOTP is requested by the user.  Because
>   of this, the counter values on the server and on the token might be
>   out of synchronization.
>
> We RECOMMEND setting a look-ahead parameter s on the server, which 
>   defines the size of the look-ahead window.  In a nutshell, the server 
>   can recalculate the next s HOTP-server values, and check them against 
>   the received HOTP client.
>
> Synchronization of counters in this scenario simply requires the
>   server to calculate the next HOTP values and determine if there is a
>   match.  Optionally, the system MAY require the user to send a
>   sequence of (say, 2, 3) HOTP values for resynchronization purpose,
>   since forging a sequence of consecutive HOTP values is even more
>   difficult than guessing a single HOTP value.
>
> The upper bound set by the parameter s ensures the server does not
>   go    on checking HOTP values forever (causing a denial-of-service
>   attack)    and also restricts the space of possible solutions for an
>   attacker    trying to manufacture HOTP values. s SHOULD be set as low
>   as    possible, while still ensuring that usability is not impacted.